# Parquet to ElasticSearchwrite

Tags: java, elasticsearch

My parquet format is
id.   JSON
where id is id of elastic search and JSON i want to put into elastic search. Below os snippet of it.

```
+---+--------------------+
|key|               value|
+---+--------------------+
|  6|{"FirstName":"pra...|
|  3|{"FirstName":["as...|
|  5|{"FirstName":"pra...|
|  4|{"FirstName":["pr...|
+---+--------------------+
```

How can i do that in Java?

Answer (score 0):

'''

```
Dataset<Row> ds =spark.read().parquet(path);
JavaPairRDD<String, String> jpRDD = ds.toJavaRDD().mapToPair(new PairFunction<Row, String, String>() {
            public Tuple2<String, String> call(Row row) throws Exception {
                return new Tuple2<String, String>((String) row.get(0), (String) row.get(1));
            }
        });
JavaEsSpark.saveToEsWithMeta(jpRDD,pathofESIndice,ImmutableMap.of("es.input.json","true"));
```

'''